# Schedule a batch for every 30 mins

Tags: apex

I could see below is the schedules for different minutes which successfully happens i am having an doubt how does it execute if the time is 1:15pm when i am using an syntax for the 15 mins schedule from 1:15pm it should show till 1:30pm but its not happening like that , can anyone tell me how does it work please its very important for me i need to schedule for 30 mins

```
System.schedule('Scheduled Job 1', '0 0 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass());
 System.schedule('Scheduled Job 2', '0 15 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass()); 
System.schedule('Scheduled Job 3', '0 30 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass()); 
System.schedule('Scheduled Job 4', '0 45 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass());
```

Comment: hmm looks like you need to schedule 15 job. Each job for each min.. If you use  syntax 15 means It will execute batch every hours of 15 mins exampl. it will run 1:15 PM, 2:15 PM, 3:15 PM etc..

Comment: Please refer this link for better clarification. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: Instead of scheduling every 30 minutes, you may want to consider "chaining" jobs using queueables or scheduling another job to run 30 minutes after the existing job completes as one of your finish methods (use an instance method if you do). Which to do would depend on how rigid your requirements are. Scheduled classes won't run exactly at the scheduled time regardless of what increment you've set for them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to schedule two jobs. The scheduler doesn't schedule in time increments but schedules on the value you pass to it. So if you pass 15 for the minutes field it will run every hour on the 15 minute mark. In your case if you want it to run every 30 mins you would need one job with the mins at 0, and one with the mins at 30 (assuming those are the marks you want it to run on).

> The System.Schedule method takes three arguments: a name for the job, **an expression used to represent the time and date the job is scheduled to run**, and the name of the class.

The link provided in the comments above is a good link of the explanation of this [interface.](http://The%20System.Schedule%20method%20takes%20three%20arguments:%20a%20name%20for%20the%20job,%20an%20expression%20used%20to%20represent%20the%20time%20and%20date%20the%20job%20is%20scheduled%20to%20run,%20and%20the%20name%20of%20the%20class.%20This%20expression%20has%20the%20following%20syntax:)